# File dialog input with pyqt4 comes up without any font glyphs

Tags: cygwin, pyqt4, crc32

I'm trying to create a GUI based application that will perform CRC match between a file copied to card and its source. I'm using PyQT4 from Cygwin with XWindows. When I open up the file dialog to browse to the file that was copied to the card, I donot see file system as one would expect to see when using QFileDialog.getOpenFileName. I see blank squares instead. I've a hunch that this might be due to the fact that it is trying to access a Unix based file system on a Windows machine. Your help is appreciated.

```
            #!/usr/bin/env python
            import zlib
            import sys
            from PyQt4.QtGui import *

            def crc(fileName, count):
                if count == 0:
                    return "%X"%(zlib.crc32(open(fileName,"rb").read()) & 0xFFFFFFFF)
                else:
                     return "%X"%(zlib.crc32(open(fileName,"rb").read(count)) & 0xFFFFFFFF)             

            def compare(cr1, crc2):
                    if crc1 == crc2:
                            return "CRC Matched"
                    else :
                            return "CRC not Equal"


            a = QApplication(sys.argv)
            w = QWidget()

            w.resize(320, 240)
            w.setWindowTitle("CRC Check")

            fileName = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(w, 'Open File', '/')

            crc1 = crc(fileName , count = 0)
            print "Generated file CRC", crc1

            crc2 = crc(fileName = "/dev/sdc", count = 5000000)
            print "Copied file CRC", crc2

            print compare(crc1, crc2)

            w.show()
            sys.exit(a.exec_())
```

Comment: I do not believe this is a problem with Python or PyQt4. This might be an issue with Cygwin or XWindows

Comment: The static `get*()` functions will use a native file dialog. Try passing the `DontUseNativeDialog` [option](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#Option-enum) to see if that makes any difference.